# Batch field-calculator with a decimal result

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, batch

Is it possible to carry out a batch field calculator process in QGIS across multiple layers resulting in a decimal number? I have manage to do it and get an integer but not a decimal. There are only options for an integer, float, date and string in the field type drop down.

I am trying to calculate the area of roughly 3900 layers so don't want to have to calculate it individually.

[image: Batch calculator resulting in an integer]

Comment: The field you are trying to write to is integer type? Add the code you used

Comment: I'm new to QGIS and even newer to coding. I didn't use and code for the answer only the field calculator function this is what the log results in:{'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
'FIELD_NAME': 'Interc km2',
'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
'FORMULA': '$Area',
'INPUT': 'Intersect SSP3BINOMIAL_Civettictis civetta',
'NEW_FIELD': True,
'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':U:/Batch Intersects/C-H/AreaIntersect SSP3BINOMIAL_Civettictis civetta.csv, 'createOptions': {}}>}

Comment: Your field is integer/whole number type. You need decimal type

Comment: there isn't an option for decimal type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filed type you should have `Float`.

[image]

Or something which work as a float type in your storage file. I see that there are different options, probaly based on the storage format: I have seen `Float`, `decimal number (real)`, Decimal number (numeric)` and so on.

This is what I got on a .shp files:

[image]

Or Postgresql:

[image]

Comment: Yes using the float worked thank you!